# Create API using Azure API management

Tags: node.js, azure

I built a web application using react and node , and also i want to build a mobile app , so i'm trying to build REST API to manage the database . I heard about the Azure API management and trying to using it  but couldn't find any tutorial that relevant with javascript 
Does Anyone know good tutorial to refer??

Answer (score 2):

Azure API Management is not intended to create API, it is intended to act as a proxy, to harden your API against attacks from outside. You should be using WebApp or ApiApp to create your API.

Comment: I've already built API using node.js , now i'm trying to connect it with azure

Comment: what does 'connect it with azure' mean?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to build Mobile App back-end on Azure with node.js SDK.

About how to use the Azure Mobile Apps Node.js SDK, you could refer to the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk.

Also, you could take the following complete series tutorial on the Node.js SDK as reference: https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/.

Any further concern or my misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: actually i can't get clear idea about what Azure API management use for can i use it to create a API , so i can access it by web and mobile

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply :D

Comment: Hi @sasy, there is a esay way to develop REST APIs through `easy api` and `easy table` on Azure. For more info, plase refer to this [blog](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/), which maybe can give you any help or hints.